# IT security or Security only?

Tags: discussion, scope

Just a thought, the site is security.stackexchange.com but the logo in the header of the page clearly says 'IT Security'.

[image]

Since a broad spectrum of questions regarding physical and procedural security are accepted here, shouldn't that be changed to just "security"?

Besides, no one ever says 'ITSec.Se'

Comment: I once got confused on Stack Overflow careers when I was trying to include my IT security account. Almost all other sites were listed (in the drop-down menu) by the sub-domain name so I kept searching for security but could not find it. Later I came to know that it was listed as ITsecurity.

Comment: This [came up](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/28/merge-with-the-security-proposal) [several](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/311/what-about-physical-security) [times](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/464/regarding-our-scope-whats-acceptable-whats-not/465#465) in the past. The site is called “IT security” for historical reasons, even though it has been broader since the beta.

Comment: Making the site moniker "Information (and more) Security.SE" (I(am) Sec.SE)) is not on the menu, right?

Comment: @deerhunter awesome!!!!

Answer (score 10):

I think it's a fundamental mistake to think that physical security isn't part of IT Security.  If someone comes on asking how to protect a diamond collection, it's off topic, but how to physically secure an office building is a critical (arguably the most critical) part of protecting the information contained within.

Comment: Agreed, there's the old saying "If you have physical access to a machine you own it". Simple as that really :)

Comment: I'd vote to close for "too localized" actually, but I see your point ;)

Comment: The FAQ says otherwise

Comment: @Griffin - not sure which of the comments that was in reference to.

Answer (score 6):

We discussed this some time back in one of our scope creep chats. I think the conclusion was that it wasn't worth the effort.

I agree that it is currently slightly misleading but the core of our scope is still IT security so I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think it's always worth the effort to rethink and improve what we have. Plus, the url doesn't state itsecurity.stackexchange.com, but security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

As Rory said, our discussion around this was going on during the same time frame as the site design and graduation. The results of those discussions have been largely captured in the FAQ, now found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> IT Security Stack Exchange is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities. Topics include, but are not limited to:
>
> web app hardening
> network security
> social engineering, including phishing
> risk management
> policies
> penetration testing
> security tools
> using cryptography
> incident response
> physically securing the office, datacentre, information assets etc.

The last two topics are really the core of what you're asking. Incident Response being a largely soft topic, with technical aspects depending on the incident. Then the last is explicitly allowing physical security topics. We do have a number of them already, not nearly as many as some other topics, but as of right now we have 100 non-deleted questions in the [physical](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical) tag.

The reason for the "IT Security" branding is exactly what Rory hinted at. By the time we had the discussion explicitly allowing physical security questions the site design had already gone through and either had gone live or was within a day or two of going live. We decided it probably wasn't worthwhile to lobby Jin for a new design removing the dreaded "T".

Comment: Very interesting, however the question was: 'shouldn't that be changed to just "security"?'. From what you say it should indeed be changed but it may be hard to convince someone to do it, right?

Comment: @Aki: It's a bit of both. First we have to answer the question, "Is is appropriate to change?" then answer "*Should* we?" so I make sure to answer both. It's definitely appropriate, but may not actually be worthwhile.